# Fix Segate's SeaTools' bad GUI scaling on Gnome desktop?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, gnome

I am using Gnome 42.3 and 200% display scaling (4K screen). I have some Seagate disks, so I guess I have to use SeaTools to check/fix disk errors (is there any alternative tool?). The problem is that the GUI of SeaTools is very crappy. It is unintuitive and for some reason, does not allow me to resize the window.

The most annoying problem is that the scaling is wrong. See the screen capture below. The texts are clipped and the window is small. Is there any way, at least, to fix the scaling?

[image]

PS: For God's sake, Seagate... A multi-billion dollar company could not hire a better GUI programmer?

Comment: No, usually you don't need any such tool. The native Linux tools for error correction are enough. SeaTools can be a valuable tool for checking the predicted lifespan of the drives and update firmware but nothing else.

Comment: @ChanganAuto So, all the "fix" or "tests" can be done without using SeaTools? Then, for example, how can I do "Long Fix All" using only native Linux tools?